# How to post values of HTML form to new HTML page using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a HTML form on 'page1.html' with four elements (textbox1, textbox2, listbox1, listbox2). on clicking submit, i want the values of these elements to be posted in table to  new page (page2.html)

Table in page 2 is as follows:

- First row : value of textbox1
- Second row column 1: value of textbox2
- Second row column 2: value of listbox1
- Third row: value of listbox2

Please help

Comment: Which server-side language are you using? Do you want to do all this in js only?

Comment: The only way that you can accomplish that is either, pass those values as a query string or stored it in a database so it can be persisted when going to the other page. Or even cookie in a desperation attempt..

Comment: looking for a javascript solution only. or can i have the table hidden in same page and post values to table after submit?

Comment: Ok. In that case you can try my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With plain `html` and `javascript` you can do like this

page1.html

```
<input type="text" id="txt1" />
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="postData()" />
```

javascript

```
function postData(){
    var val = document.getElementById("txt1").value;

    var tbl = "<table><tr><td>"+val+"</td></tr></table>";

    var w = window.open("page2.html");

    w.document.write(tbl);
}
```

Comment: submit does not open page2.html

Comment: @user1994366 Check the code now. I changed this `var tbl = "<table><tr><td>".val."</td></tr></table>";` to this `var tbl = "<table><tr><td>"+val+"</td></tr></table>";`

Comment: @user1994366 In `javascript` the concatenation operator is `+` but i used wrongs as `.` and so you may be getting errors, try the updated code now.

Answer (score 2):

Here You can use a form with `type = GET` and `action="page2.html"`

Then in `page2.html`, in pageload use the following function to extract the URL parameters

```
function getURLParameter(name) {
    return decodeURI(
        (RegExp(name + '=' + '(.+?)(&|$)').exec(location.search)||[,null])[1]
    );
}
```

****Demo:****

**Page1.html**

```
<form type="GET" action="page2.html">
<input name="text" id="txt" />
</form>
```

**Page2.html**

```
<script>
function getURLParameter(name) {
    return decodeURI(
        (RegExp(name + '=' + '(.+?)(&|$)').exec(location.search)||[,null])[1]
    );
}
alert(getURLParameter("text"));
</script>
```